# Dailymotion API Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, youtube, dailymotion-api

Hope someone will be able to help me,
I am currently working on a flash project and i have to play youtube and dailymotion video. (this application is full actionscript3 not in a flash app in a browser).

I am trying to make the actionscript youtube api and it does work i can load and play videos.
But when i am trying to use the dailymotion api in actionscript3 : http://www.dailymotion.com/fr/doc/api/player-deprecated/flash_api

I can display the api, load videos, but when it comes to play i get those message:
One is about Sandbox violation, 
another message is : interruption of your connection something called l2 visiblemeasures.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please copy and paste the error messages you're receiving.

Answer (score 1):

You probably use the Flash player content debugger. 
When using the standard Flash Player (not the content debugger one) those messages should not be displayed and the video should play normally and smoothly. 
Sandbox violation might occur in some cases when no crossdomain policy is setup.
Those messages are not critical as long as they don't crash the player and the streaming when using standard Flash Player.

Best.